# Date & Price field should be defined as Index or just Stored in Solr 3.6?

Tags: solr, solrnet

Using Solr 3.6, I'm confused about considering a field as index or not..

For specifically two field, named Created Date, and Price. I need to have filter on both of them, but can't decide whether they should be defined as Index or not in Schema.xml.

Does it have any performance impact, and to create filter is it required to be indexed or just keeping them as stored will do the work?

Any idea on this will be great.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you will use those fields. Firstly, if you need to make query on the both create date and price fields then you should set indexed to true for both fields. Secondly, if you want users retrieve create date and price fields in the search result then you should also set stored to true. Otherwise you can set them false.